# Swift check if class conforms to protocol always true

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

```
protocol Device {
}
protocol ActiveDevice: Device {
}
protocol NoActive: Device {
}
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
  let device: Device
}
```

Setting device for ViewController. currentDevice is an object which conforms to protocol Device

```
vc.device = currentDevice as! ActiveDevice
```

Checking if it conforms to the protocol:

```
    if let currentDevice = device as? NoActive  {
        print("Its not active device")
    }else if let currentDevice = device as? ActiveDevice {
        print("Its active device")
    }else {
        print("Its just a device")
    }
```

It always prints `Its not active device` what I would expect in this case that it would print `Its active device`

Comment: You can not initialize a `protocol` as `ActiveDevice()`. Not sure if this will help to understand the actual issue.

Comment: Yea, in this case, I'm setting object which confronts to ActiveDevice protocol to the device in controller

Comment: I think, current code is not sufficient to figure out the issue.

Comment: What is `vc` in your code? and I think you should make the property variable to assign it later on `let device: Device`.

Comment: Generally protocol are used to communicate between two entities say 2 controllers for example. What you want to achieve here and I think you can simply assign the protocol to specific one, conform like `OldViewController: UIViewController, ActiveDevice` and just assign as `vc.device = self`, where vc would be instantiated object of `ViewController`, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code and let me know if this helps.

```
protocol Device {
}
protocol ActiveDevice: Device {
}
protocol NoActive: Device {
}

// class TestDevice: Device {
// class TestDevice: ActiveDevice {
class TestDevice: NoActive {

}

let currentDevice = TestDevice()

// let device: Device = currentDevice as! ActiveDevice
(It threw error as "Could not cast value of type '__lldb_expr_9.TestDevice' (0x11a2f9090) to '__lldb_expr_9.ActiveDevice' (0x11a6d0628)."). We cannot do this.

let device: Device = currentDevice


if device is NoActive  {
    print("Its not active device")
}else if device is ActiveDevice {
    print("Its active device")
}else {
    print("Its just a device")
}
```

Now, the output is "Its not active device". And after changing the TestDevice to "ActiveDevice", it printed "Its active device" and so on.

Comment: @kosas, Was this helpful? is your problem resolved?